# MySql query to find columns containing certain variables MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find search across multiple columns that may contain certain characters, I have two questions. Using MySQL and PHP

1.
I have found out how to concatenate the columns and can search things like it, but there are many things I have to search for in them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM sessions
WHERE CONCAT( session_id, config_id, sessionDate, sessionLength, userEmail, clientEmail, emailSent, UDID, deviceLocation, company ) 
LIKE  "%"$sessionId"%" 

or 
WHERE CONCAT( session_id, config_id, sessionDate, sessionLength, userEmail, clientEmail, emailSent, UDID, deviceLocation, company )
like "%"$clientId"%"

or 
WHERE CONCAT( session_id, config_id, sessionDate, sessionLength, userEmail, clientEmail, emailSent, UDID, deviceLocation, company )
like "%"$date"%"

or 
WHERE CONCAT( session_id, config_id, sessionDate, sessionLength, userEmail, clientEmail, emailSent, UDID, deviceLocation, company )
like "%"$email"%"

or 
WHERE CONCAT( session_id, config_id, sessionDate, sessionLength, userEmail, clientEmail, emailSent, UDID, deviceLocation, company )
like "%"$sessionId"%"
```

2.
I am not sure if the "%"$sessionId"%" "%"$clientId"% ect. will work like that so feel free to substitute it with things like "%SNAKE%" "%Solid%" and if they don't work like I think they do how could I do it using those variables. Once again this is in PHP

Comment: It would seem to me like a poor DB design if there's any possibility that the `$sessionId` variable would be anyway other than the `session_id` column. Is this behaviour intentional? Sounds like it's well worth avoiding. This approach is only going to get messy.

Comment: I am taking apart a search that people enter something like "be I 52 2001" and storing each word in a variable. so sessionId could be equal to "be", and email could be equal to "52". Therefore I need to search through let's say userEmail with $sessionId and session_Id with $email. They are not the final variable names, it was just a trial of names.

Comment: Better alternatives (from a database perspective) would be to determine which field each search term belongs to (e.g. if it can be parsed as a date, it's a date) or to require some terms to use [operators](http://stackoverflow.com/search) (like SO does with "user:", "votes:" &c). [Describe the goal](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal), not just the step, so you don't fall victim to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless what you really want to gain from your query, you can compose your query in a php line like this

```
"SELECT @a:= '".$sessionId."|".$cilentId."|".$date."|".$email."', * FROM sessions s
WHERE s.session_id REGEXP @a OR s.cilentId REGEXP @a OR s.date REGEXP @a OR s.email REGEXP @a"
```

You can experiement with this query in mysql

```
select @a:='mon|ues|dnesd', 
'monday' regexp @a or "tuesday" regexp @a or "wednesday" regexp @a
```

modify @a value and see 0/1 logic in the result.

Comment: The potential for injection attacks (and related bugs, due to mixing of host & embedded language) is high.

Comment: Definitely, but this was not the question (suppose the values are strongly validated before being inserted into the query text).

Comment: Assuming anything about security gets you in trouble. Even if the OP doesn't ask about some important aspect (such as security), an answer should at least include a note if that aspect isn't addressed. There are too many copy-and-paste coders out there. Also, this could easily be rewritten to use a prepared statement.